# Map function class member inside class itself

Tags: c++, stdmap, std-function

I have difficulty to map the functions of the class member inside the class itself

```
#include <functional>
#include <map>
#include <string>

class Foo{
    public:
    void bar() {}
    void jar() {}

    private:
    std::map<std::string, std::function<void(void)>> myMap =
    {
        {"bar", bar},
        {"jar", jar}
    };
};
```

The compiler says no

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State   Suppression State
Error (active)  E0289   no instance of constructor "std::map<_Kty, _Ty, _Pr, _Alloc>::map [with _Kty=std::string, _Ty=std::function, _Pr=std::less, _Alloc=std::allocator>>]" matches the argument list   Stackoverflow   C:\Stackoverflow\Foo.h  13

Please help, thank you.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the full error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bar` and `jar` are member functions. They take pointer - `this` as first hidden parameter, you cannot treat them as free-functions. And you cannot just wrap them into `function<void(void)>` by taking pointers to them - what you are doing now.

You should use `std::bind` to bind `this` to member functions (or use lambda expressions):

```
std::map<std::string, std::function<void(void)> > myMap2 =
{
    {"bar", std::bind(&Foo::bar,this)},
    {"jar", std::bind(&Foo::jar,this)}
};
```

or store pointers to functions:

```
std::map<std::string, void (Foo::*)(void) > myMap =
{
    {"bar", &Foo::bar},
    {"jar", &Foo::jar}
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Some alternatives to @rafix07's answer:

Using lambdas with `this` capture:

```
std::map<std::string, std::function<void(void)> > myMap2 =
{
    {"bar", [this]{ bar(); }},
    {"jar", [this]{ jar(); }}
};
```

or taking member function pointers into a `std::function`:

```
std::map<std::string, std::function<void(Foo*)> > myMap2 =
{
    {"bar", &Foo::bar},
    {"jar", &Foo::jar}
};
```

Note that the notation `&Foo::` is required to obtain a pointer to a non-static member function. Neither `&bar` or `bar` are allowed the way they are for free functions.